# Issue of tintColor for navigation bar in iOS 4 and iOS 5

Tags: ios5, ios4, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

I have set tint color for navigation bar like

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = 
    [UIColor colorWithRed:168.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

This works in iOS 5 and above. But in iOS 4 and below iOS 5 its just black color. The tint color is not set.

Comment: test with [UIColor redColor]; And is that work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work.. :(

Answer (score 0):

for UISWitch tintColor is only for IOS 6.0 and later.
so probably on IOS 5.0 should crash